# Different results on same expression

Tags: r, sum, combinations

I have the following code snippets sum `s` which i have written in two ways. Both the expressions although are same, giving me two different answers. The output is coming to be negative where it is supposed to come in a positive value. Please tell me why it is happening and how to rectify it.

```
n <- 40
k <- 20
m <- 30
T <- 1.2
t1 <- 3
```

(1) The first way of expressing the sum

```
s <- 0

for (j in 0:(m-1)) {
  a <- choose(m-1, j)*(-1)^j*(1/(n-m+1+j))*(1-exp(-T*(n-m+1+j)*(1/t1)))
  s <- s + a
}

s <- s * m*choose(n, m)
```

(2) The second way of expressing the same sum is

```
s <- 0

for (j in 0:(m-1)) {
  a <- choose(m-1, j)*(-1)^j*(1/(n-m+1+j))*(1-exp(-T*(n-m+1+j)*(1/t1)))*m*choose(n, m)
  s <- s + a
}
```

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: I don't get the same values from both expressions (copy pasting your code and checking the value of `s` after that).

Comment: It's due to floating point accuracy, when you perform the multiplication in the loop, the loss of accuracy happens 30 times (and cumulates), while when you multiply at the end you lose the accuracy just once. The `s` value (not multiplied by `m*choose(n,m)` is really close to zero

Comment: @PaulHiemstra yes, that is what is happening. Both the expressions are same but giving different values. I am still to find a reason causing the difference.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Where can we find the reference expressions you are trying to implement?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra actually I did a calculation and ended up with this expression which I want to implement on R for numerical purpose.

Comment: @digEmAll so how can i take care of that and what should i do ?

Comment: @pinku: unless you can scale the calculation in order to work with numbers belonging to comparable orders of magnitude (I mean, looking at the values `s` is around `1e^-10` while `m*choose(n,m)` is `2.5^10`, the difference in magnitude is huge!!), I think the first approach is the most accurate but still I'm not completely sure about it...